# некорректная версия библиотеки при установке с nuget

Tags: c#, nuget

установил в проект библиотеку System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions с nuget

в nuget показывает версию 4.5.3

а в ссылках 4.2.0.1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если смотреть версию у файла библиотеки при сборке, то там вообще версия 4.6.27818.1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как итог при запуске приложения получаю ошибку:

Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" либо одну из их зависимостей. Найденное определение манифеста сборки не соответствует ссылке на сборку. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131040)

как добавить в проект необходимую версию ?

Comment: Посмотрите, что у вас в package.json про эту сборку написано. У вас же Xamarin?

Comment: @avocado03, нет, у меня сервис на .NETFramework 4.7.2

в packages.config:
<package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.3" targetFramework="net472" />

Comment: а вот в файле проекта:
<Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">                                                               <HintPath>..\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.3\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>                                                                                </Reference>

Comment: пробовал удалять и ставить заново, не помогло

Comment: как решилась проблема?